# Как проверить функцию на карирование?

Tags: javascript

Как проверить являеться функция карированой или нет

я хочу вызывать ее либо так

```
sum(1, 2) // результат 3
```

либо так

```
sum(1, 2)(3) // резултьтат 6
```

Проблема в том что я понимаю как сделать это при карировваном варианте, но при этом я не понимаю как вызывать ее при варианте sum(1, 2) так как она возвращает [Function].

```js
function sum(...rest1) {
  return function(...rest2) {
    let counter = 0
    Array.prototype.concat(rest1, rest2).forEach((n) => {
      counter += n
    })
    return counter
  }
}

console.log(sum(1, 2)(3))
```

Как организовать проверку внутри тела функции на то являеться она карированой или нет, когда колличество аргументов неизвестно?

Как можно сделать так что бы данная функция работала если ее вызвать как sum(1, 2) и sum(1, 2)(3)?

Comment: ась? ..............

Comment: По нормальному никак

Comment: В таких задачах важно задать самому себе вопрос, а как это должно работать. По вашей задаче лично я вижу уравнение со всеми неизвестными. Как можно определить должна функция вернуть функцию или значение, если она не знает, сколько еще аргументов ждать? Единственное что могу предложить - добавить в возвращемые функции другую функцию и возвращать в ней значение. Например: sum(1, 2)(3).eval() // 6

Comment: @NocteFury  я дописал вопрос

Comment: А я повторюсь. Как вы собираетесь определять что нужно вернуть, если не знаете когда это делать, так как количество аргументов динамическое? Притом не просто динамическое, а не известное.

Comment: @NocteFury я как раз это понимаю, поэтому и задал вопрос. Может можно как то определить что первая функция возвращает другую функцию

Comment: Ровно так как вы хотите не получится, хоть ты тресни. Чтобы сделать как вы хотите, вам нужно иметь конкретное количество аргументов. Функция не может вам вернуть в вашем первом примере число, если во втором (при тех же аргументах) возвращает функцию. Так работает JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы никогда не можете знать, как будет применяться ваша функция в дальнейшем. К примеру, на первой строке вы можете сделать так:

```
let a = sum(1,2);
```

Проблема в том, что через тысячу строк это может быть вызвано кем-то как функция `a(1,2)`, так и в тоже самое время использоваться напрямую как значение `c = a + 10`. Следовательно вам нужно знать наперед, как будет использоваться функция в будущем. Либо ей нужно быть одновременно и функцией и числом, что в принципе невозможно.

Можно конечно ломать язык и изощрятся подобным образом, но никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах не пишите подобный код в реальных проектах. Как минимум, это может иметь непредсказуемые последствия в других примерах кода.

```js
function sum(...rest1) {
  let func = function(...rest2) {
    let counter = 0
    Array.prototype.concat(rest1, rest2).forEach((n) => {
      counter += n
    })
    return counter
  }
  func.toString = func.valueOf = function() { return rest1.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) }
  return func;
}

console.log(sum(1,2))
console.log(sum(1,2)(3,4))
```

Comment: вместо forEach надо было тоже reduce использовать :-) плюс rest parameters - это всегда массив, поэтому можно без `Array.prototype.concat` сразу `rest1.concat(rest2)`

Comment: @Grundy, да у меня привычка, не менять код авторов, без веских на то оснований. Поэтому за комментарий спасибо, будет полезно автору, если захочет улучшить код.

Comment: Хотел попробовать через [Proxy с apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) - а оказалось, что этот хук работает только если target прокси тоже можно как функцию вызвать. А то могло быть красивей.

Comment: @Grundy я тоже сначала думал про proxy, но не сообразил как

Comment: @AlexKrass поясни пожалуйста что происходит и как это работает с toSting и valueOf

Comment: @Burg, что происходит в дубликате описано, трюк с toString/valueOf - проходит в случае, когда результат используется в операциях приводящих аргументы к примитивным значениям

Comment: @Burg, советую посмотреть дубликат, который откопал Grundy, там достаточно хороший пример он описал. А так фокус прост, это обычная функция. Но если объект участвует в выражении (а функция это тоже объект), то происходит его преобразование к другим типам. Вот за то, во что он будет преобразован и отвечают valueOf и toString. В общем их описание в том же mdn само за себя говорит.

Comment: @Burg, http://underscorejs.ru/#chain

Comment: @Burg, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuBbaBvAUNaAHATgSwDcwAXAU2gH1gB7eAOzJ2gF5oAGDaIkeUgCgCUqTphp0IxLmBAtoxABZ4IAOiq0GpHCLmKVa+o1kdMmHKWLwcdKSE4BfThCR9lrukgBGmgDJLiALmh3RC8cAG0AXSF0EyDPHz9lADNqHABRMGB5PmtmAD5UHSVVGgNNaABqVms7AW0zCysiiHs0BzEJaBhq0gB3OCQ0NA7qEFJlEGoAcz5HbWUnRD4AJgAaaAAWOtjlbl5BNDqRsYnp2cwWncWV9a3564BWbZNd6X26gSA

Comment: @Burg, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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

Comment: есть разные способы "сделать это правильно"

Answer (score 2):

В javascript такой фокус вряд ли пройдет.

Самое простое -- сделать две функции с разными именами.
Или делать `sum(a)(b)(c)()`, `sum(a)(b)()`.

В scala такое сделать можно, т. к. типизация статическая, но даже там не рекоммендуют.

---

В **javascript фокус проходит** с `valueOf` (век живи ...)